# PHPUnit mocked methods don't work since phpunit-mock-objects v3.2.4

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, symfony

Before creating an issue, people use to post a question here, to see if it is not a code error.

This is exactly what I am doing now, because it seems that mocking object methods does not work since phpunit-mock-objects was upgraded to version 3.2.4.

I did a rollback to 3.2.3 and everything works fine. I tried to find a changelog or a piece of documentation about the mocked methods, but the documentation is the same and I can't find a other changelog than phpunit global one.

My code is :

```
public function getAssociationRepositoryMock() {
    $repositoryMock = $this
        ->getMockBuilder('AppBundle\Repository\Troop\AssociationRepository')
        ->setMethods(['findBy'])
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock()
    ;
    $repositoryMock
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('findBy')
        ->willReturnCallback([$this, 'getUnassignedMembersMock'])
    ;
    return $repositoryMock;
}
```

The error is :

```
1) Tests\AppBundle\Manager\TroopManagerTest::testGetUnassignedMembers
Undefined index: findBy
```

Ty for your help, or for approbation of the issue creation :D !

Comment: Have you tried removing this line: `->setMethods(['findBy'])` ? If your class has that method this would be useless I guess...

Comment: Yes I tried, but I also had an error !

```1) Tests\AppBundle\Manager\TroopManagerTest::testGetUnassignedMembers
Trying to configure method "findBy" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static```

Comment: Could you paste the class `AssociationRepository`

Comment: Actually this class isn't written. Because It is the repository system of Doctrine, which creates a repository class for each mapped entity. It worked fine until now. But you gave me the idea to try to mock ```Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository``` instead and it worked with the latest phpunit-mock-objects version. Can't figure out why, but it is a possible way to resolve the issue :).

Comment: Glad you found a solution, happy coding :)

Comment: Just FYI: Here is what changed: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/commit/4e83390f64e7ce04fcaec2ce95cd72823b431d19   - couldn't really affect your code.